# Understanding output of GHC's +RTS -t -RTS option

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm benchmarking the memory consumption of a haskell programm compiled with GHC. In order to do so, I run the programm with the following command line arguments: `+RTS -t -RTS`. Here's an example output:
`<<ghc: 86319295256 bytes, 160722 GCs, 53963869/75978648 avg/max bytes residency (386 samples), 191M in use, 0.00 INIT (0.00 elapsed), 152.69 MUT (152.62 elapsed), 58.85 GC (58.82 elapsed) :ghc>>`.
According to the ghc manual, the output shows:

- The total number of bytes allocated by the program over the whole run.
- The total number of garbage collections performed.
- The average and maximum "residency", which is the amount of live data in bytes. The runtime can only determine the amount of live data during a major GC, which is why the number of samples corresponds to the number of major GCs (and is usually relatively small).
- The peak memory the RTS has allocated from the OS.
- The amount of CPU time and elapsed wall clock time while initialising the runtime system (INIT), running the program itself (MUT, the mutator), and garbage collecting (GC).

Applied to my example, it means that my program shuffles 82321 MiB (bytes divided by 1024^2) around, performs 160722 garbage collections, has a 51MiB/72MiB average/maximum memory residency, allocates at most 191M memory in RAM and so on ...

Now I want to know, what »The average and maximum "residency", which is the amount of live data in bytes« is compared to »The peak memory the RTS has allocated from the OS«? And also: What uses the remaining space of roughly 120M?

I was pointed [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.1/GHC-Stats.html) for more information, but that does not state clearly, what I want to know. Another [source](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/prof-heap.html) (5.4.4 second item) hints that the 120M memory is used for garbage collection. But that is too vague – I need a quotable information source.

So please, is there anyone who could answer my questions with good sources as proofs?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 4):

The "resident" size is how much live Haskell data you have. The amount of memory actually allocated from the OS may be higher.

- The RTS allocates memory in "blocks". If your program needs 7.3 blocks of of RAM, the RTS has to allocate 8 blocks, 0.7 of which is empty space.
- The default garbage collection algorithm is a 2-space collector. That is, when space A fills up, it allocates space B (which is totally empty) and copies all the live data out of space A and into space B, then deallocates space A. That means that, for a while, you're using 2x as much RAM as is actually necessary. (I believe there's a switch somewhere to use a 1-space algorithm which is slower but uses less RAM.)

There is also some overhead for managing threads (especially if you have lots), and there might be a few other things.

I don't know how much you already know about GC technology, but you can try reading these:

- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/parallel-gc/par-gc-ismm08.pdf
- http://www.mm-net.org.uk/workshop190404/GHC%27s_Garbage_Collector.ppt

Comment: Could you explain what live data (and maybe also »dead data«) is? Could you also provide a link that backs up your information and maybe goes deeper into explaining how the garbage collection in GHC works? That would be very nice. Kind regards!

Comment: I don't know much about GCs, so introductive literature would be great. The mentioned paper goes too much into details and does not help me interpreting my scenario – the presentation is easier to understand but I don't get the point.